# On burning new iso image onto CD (rw type), still the CD reflects the old content!

Tags: burning

I had got "Windows repair disc" iso burnt on my CD (of RW type but not sure weather its CD +RW or CD -RW).

As its `RW`, it means the CD can be written multiple times.

So, today I want to burn it with an iso file on my hard disk which contains photos & a video. So, I ran:

```
sudo wodim test.iso
```

It had output that *these many* data written on disk, *this* was the burning rate, etc. But when I view the contents of the CD by mounting it, I see only the previous data of the "Windows repair disc". No photo or video is there. What may be the reason & what happened actually?

> EDIT#1

As per slm's answer, I tried but didn't work. Please see below.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ wodim -VV dev=/dev/cdrw blank=all >a2.lst 2>a2error.lst
```

The content of a2error.lst (output shown below is pruned):

```
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.

Executing 'test unit ready' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 40s
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s
.......
........
.......... (removed to bring the character size of this Q in limit)
............
Executing 'blank unit' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 9600s
CDB:  A1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), blank unit scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  A1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 00 30 05 00 00
Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x30 Qual 0x05 (cannot write medium - incompatible format) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 0.001s timeout 9600s
wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.

Executing 'flush cache' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 120s
CDB:  35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 120s

Executing 'test unit ready' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 40s
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s
Mode Parameters (un-converted) 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Mode Parameters 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00

Executing 'mode select g1' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 40s
CDB:  55 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00
Sending 16 (0x10) bytes of data.
Write Data:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s

Executing 'prevent/allow medium removal' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 40s
CDB:  1E 00 00 00 00 00
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s
```

Please note the line in the above error list "wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.".

I tried the below also but didn't work:

```
wodim blank=fast
```

Below is the last 3 lines of the output:

```
wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
wodim: Some drives do not support all blank types.
wodim: Try again with wodim blank=all.
```

> EDIT#2

As per the comment of slm, please see the output of the command below. This also didn't work.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ cdrecord blank=fast dev=1,0,0
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
WARNING: the deprecated pseudo SCSI syntax found as device specification.
Support for that may cease in the future versions of wodim. For now,
the device will be mapped to a block device file where possible.
Run "wodim --devices" for details.
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

When I run 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'; it outputs "no such file or directory; Cannot open SCSI driver!"

> EDIT#3

As per the comment, I'm adding below the command & its output.

```
$ wodim -prcap >s1 2>s2
$ cat s1

Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'PIONEER '
Identification : 'DVD-RW DVRKD08RS'
Revision       : '1.02'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing

  Does read Mode 2 Form 1 blocks
  Does read Mode 2 Form 2 blocks
  Does read digital audio blocks
  Does restart non-streamed digital audio reads accurately
  Does support Buffer-Underrun-Free recording
  Does read multi-session CDs
  Does read fixed-packet CD media using Method 2
  Does not read CD bar code
  Does not read R-W subcode information
  Does read raw P-W subcode data from lead in
  Does return CD media catalog number
  Does return CD ISRC information
  Does not support C2 error pointers
  Does not deliver composite A/V data

  Does play audio CDs
  Number of volume control levels: 256
  Does support individual volume control setting for each channel
  Does support independent mute setting for each channel
  Does not support digital output on port 1
  Does not support digital output on port 2

  Loading mechanism type: tray
  Does support ejection of CD via START/STOP command
  Does not lock media on power up via prevent jumper
  Does allow media to be locked in the drive via PREVENT/ALLOW command
  Is not currently in a media-locked state
  Does not support changing side of disk
  Does not have load-empty-slot-in-changer feature
  Does not support Individual Disk Present feature

  Maximum read  speed:  4233 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current read  speed:  4233 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Maximum write speed:  4233 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current write speed:  4233 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Rotational control selected: CLV/PCAV
  Buffer size in KB: 2000
  Copy management revision supported: 1
  Number of supported write speeds: 5
  Write speed # 0:  4233 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Write speed # 1:  3528 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  20x, DVD  2x)
  Write speed # 2:  2822 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  16x, DVD  2x)
  Write speed # 3:  1764 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  10x, DVD  1x)
  Write speed # 4:   705 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD   4x, DVD  0x)

Supported CD-RW media types according to MMC-4 feature 0x37:
  Does write multi speed       CD-RW media
  Does write high  speed       CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed  CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed+ CD-RW media

$ cat s2
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

Comment: Did you try `wodim blank=fast` first?

Comment: @goldilocks I tried just now what you told but didn't work. Please see the end part of my edit.

Comment: Use `wodim -prcap`. This is a known issue with `wodim`. Also you can do `wodim dev=/dev/sr0 --devices` or `wodim dev=/dev/sr0 --scanbus`. See my Q&A about this here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110993/getting-capabilities-of-my-cd-dvd-drive-when-wodim-devices-doesnt-work

Comment: @slm Please write the final command to run for blanking the CD.

Comment: @Ravi - I need to see the output from one of the commands I posted to continue.

Comment: @slm please have a look at my Q (EDIT#3) for the same

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ubuntu CD/DVD Burning guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning):

*excerpt*

> #### Blanking a CD/RW
>
> To reuse a rewritable CD or DVD you first need to 'blank' the disk. This erases the old data and prepares the disk for new data. First of all, make sure the CD has been unmounted.
>
> ```
>     $ umount /dev/cdrw
> ```
>
> Then, type the following command, which will erase all the content inside the disk. Operation might take a while and executing the below command as is will only give you a 'Blanking entire disk' message with no progress bar or percentage display.
>
> ```
>     $ wodim -vv dev=/dev/cdrw blank=all
> ```

#### wodim man page

Additionally from the `wodim` man page:

*excerpt*

```
  blank=type
          Blank a CD-RW and exit or blank a CD-RW before writing. The 
          blanking type may be one of:

          help        Display a list of possible blanking types.
          all         Blank the entire disk. This may take a long time.
          fast        Minimally blank the disk. This results in erasing the
                      PMA, the TOC and the pregap.
          track       Blank a track.
          unreserve   Unreserve a reserved track.
          trtail      Blank the tail of a track.
          unclose     Unclose last session.
          session     Blank the last session.
```

The man page also had this to say on blanking + medium:

> Not all drives support all blanking types. It may be necessary to use 
>   `blank=all` if a drive reports a specified command as being invalid.  If used 
>   together with the -force flag, this option may be used to blank CD-RW disks that otherwise cannot be blanked. Note that you may need to specify blank=all because some  drives will  not  continue with certain types of bad CD-RW disks. Note also that `wodim` does its best if the `-force` flag is used but it finally depends on the drive's firmware whether the blanking operation will succeed  or
>   not.

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned but didn't work. Please have a look at my edited Q.

Comment: As an alternative to `wodim` please try this: `cdrecord blank=fast dev=1,0,0`.

Comment: I ran the command but this also didn't work. Please see EDIT#2 in my Q.