# Getting capabilities of my CD/DVD drive when wodim --devices doesn't work

Tags: linux, fedora, hardware, data-cd

I used to be able to run either commands successfully on my Fedora 14 Thinkpad T410 laptop:

```
$ wodim --scanbus
$ wodim --devices
```

However since upgrading to Fedora 19 this no longer seems to work and I'm not sure why. Are there any alternative methods for getting the drives capabilities from `wodim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to confirm this is truly a bug or not but this Ubuntu bug would seem to lead credence to this assumption, titled: "[wodim doesn't find my DVD writer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cdrkit/+bug/1203559)".

This thread listed a workaround by including the `dev=` to `wodim`. This works so long as you know your CD/DVD devices handle.

*--scanbus*

```
$ wodim dev=/dev/sr0 --scanbus
scsibus1:
    1,0,0   100) 'Optiarc ' 'DVD RW AD-7930H ' '1.D1' Removable CD-ROM
    1,1,0   101) *
    1,2,0   102) *
    1,3,0   103) *
    1,4,0   104) *
    1,5,0   105) *
    1,6,0   106) *
    1,7,0   107) *
```

*--devices*

```
$ wodim dev=/dev/sr0 --devices 
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sr0'  rwrw-- : 'Optiarc' 'DVD RW AD-7930H'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### An alternative?

As an alternative you can also list the devices in `wodim` without having to know the device ahead of time by using the `-prcap` switch.

```
$ wodim -prcap
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/sr0
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'Optiarc '
Identification : 'DVD RW AD-7930H '
Revision       : '1.D1'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing
  ...
```

This 3rd method would seem to be the best option.

Comment: Nice, +1. On my system, I needed to both specify the device _and_ use the `prcap` flag to get my drive's capabilities: `wodim dev=/dev/sr0 -prcap`.