# CentOS 6.4: Unable to mount disc, doesn't like UDF

Tags: centos, mount, udf

I'm trying to use a CD on CentOS 6.4, but I keep getting this error:

> Unable to mount Disc
> Error mounting: mount: unknown filesystem type 'udf'

I've installed `udftools`

I've tried changing the permissions around on `/dev/sr0` to no avail.

I've tried various ways of mounting the disc such as:

- `mount /dev/sr0 /mnt` (unknown filesystem type 'udf')
- `mount -t auto /dev/sr0 /mnt` (unknown filesystem type 'udf')
- `mount -r -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt` (wrong fs type...)
- `mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /mnt` (unknown filesystem type 'udf', despite being in the man page for mount)
- `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=disc.iso` -> `mount -o loop disc.iso /mnt -t iso9660`

I can see and read from the disc just fine in a VM on that host and on other physical machines.

It also seems to happen with just about every disc that I've tried.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you mounting as your username or as root?

Comment: Also please provide the output from `wodim`: `wodim dev=/dev/sr0 --scanbus`. If that doesn't work try this: ` wodim -prcap`.

Comment: BTW this is happening as root

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured out the issue. Someone had added a line in this file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/disabled.conf
```

that said:

```
install udf /bin/false
```

I simply commented it out, and I'm now able to mount discs.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but it got disabled by a CIS security baseline setting located at the following location:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/cis_disable_fs.conf
```

Commented the install udf /bin/true line and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message. Checked `/etc/modprobe.d` and found a file called `usgcb.blacklist`. In there it had.....

```
install udf /bin/true
```

Commented it out and now our system can read a CD-ROM

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange @TR55!
Would you be able to provide information on what does that configuration does? It is not clear to what happens if your advice is followed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say this but I get the impression you're attempting to mount the DVD drive using just your regular userid, which typically is not allowed to make use of the `mount` command as you're attempting to do so.

To mount using `mount` you typically need to be root or have `sudo` privileges to do this:

```
$ sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /mnt
```

This command should typically "just work" on most Linuxes. Occasionally you might need to do it like so:

```
$ sudo mount -t udf /dev/dvd /mnt
```

#### Drive capabilities

If you're not having any luck you can check your drives capabilities using the command line tool `wodim`.

```
$ wodim -prcap
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/sr0
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'Optiarc '
Identification : 'DVD RW AD-7930H '
Revision       : '1.D1'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing
```

#### References

- [Getting capabilities of my CD/DVD drive when wodim --devices doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110993/getting-capabilities-of-my-cd-dvd-drive-when-wodim-devices-doesnt-work/110994#110994)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it on Tuesday when I'm back on site.