# CD disk not detected by Fedora on my Laptop

Tags: fedora, mount, automounting, dvd

I rarely use cd's on my laptop, but I recall having the same problem a few months ago. When I put a cd in my DVD drive nothing happens. It kicked in last time without me doing anything but I don't know what's wrong. I need to burn a cd with k3b but it gives the error "no optical device found".

My system is Fedora 20 x86_64.
Problem: CD's don't get mounted, when inserted in the drive nothing happens.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

**UPDATE CURRENT:
Problem: cd's and dvd's are not working properly, since march they have been unstable as in "not mounting when inserted", "mounting when inserted but disconnecting at random"/"unmonting at random", when disconneted the disk is invisible to the system and I can't eject the disk.**

I put a dvd movie in the drive yesterday, it got mounted in /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT and eveything worked, then after a while it dissapeared, was not mounted anymore and I can not eject the dvd from the drive. This is how it is now, it's still in the drive, here are some commands that work on the drive as is now:

```
root ~ # dmesg | grep -E 'cd|cdrom|cd/rw|dvd|writer|sr0'
[    1.239250] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.248714] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.2-201.fc20.x86_64 ehci_hcd
[    1.249119] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.249150] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.249308] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.249439] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.249527] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.249553] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.249638] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.2-201.fc20.x86_64 xhci_hcd
[    1.252451] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.252613] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.252661] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.2-201.fc20.x86_64 xhci_hcd
[    1.652308] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.652311] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.652453] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.828890] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   40.830788] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[   41.739818] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[   41.739847] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[ 1809.110149] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 enp0s20u2: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device
[ 1825.135250] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1831.390781] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1831.558257] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[17250.764324] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[17264.847506] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[17270.813900] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[17270.980819] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[35215.177879] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[35227.560848] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[35228.671372] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[35228.838613] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[35917.047630] SELinux: initialized (dev sr0, type udf), uses genfs_contexts
[44806.808009] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[44807.324227] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[44807.880434] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[44856.000206] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[44856.319338] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[44980.675383] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[59345.299819] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[78891.591565] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[78897.855153] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[78898.022399] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[83262.678186] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 enp0s20u2: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device
[83278.871637] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[83279.952077] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[83280.118951] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[95425.784192] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 62x/62x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[95425.785279] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[95449.052453] SELinux: initialized (dev sr0, type udf), uses genfs_contexts
[98370.811692] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[98386.604469] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[98387.914034] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[98388.080693] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[100738.953863] traps: dvdrip[647] general protection ip:7fa7847e3561 sp:7fff325fdbd0 error:0 in liboxygen-gtk.so[7fa78477f000+150000]
[122586.181343] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[122600.093624] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[122601.554193] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[122601.721759] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[132184.067563] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[139533.563004] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[139534.653429] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[139534.820139] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[139676.985518] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[167212.674495] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[167213.774791] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[167213.941249] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[192379.837441] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 enp0s20u2: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device
[192396.388996] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[192397.939646] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[192398.106156] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[192659.266621] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[192676.002675] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[192677.093245] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[192677.260545] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
[208218.088226] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[208244.096626] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[208245.587341] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
```

---

```
root ~ # df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-3                         89G   63G   21G  75% /
devtmpfs                         5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            5.9G  3.9M  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.9G  9.1M  5.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            5.9G   88K  5.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2                        477M  131M  317M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                        200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-home  360G  222G  134G  63% /home
```

---

```
root ~ # cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info
CD-ROM information, Id: cdrom.c 3.20 2003/12/17

drive name:
drive speed:
drive # of slots:
Can close tray:
Can open tray:
Can lock tray:
Can change speed:
Can select disk:
Can read multisession:
Can read MCN:
Reports media changed:
Can play audio:
Can write CD-R:
Can write CD-RW:
Can read DVD:
Can write DVD-R:
Can write DVD-RAM:
Can read MRW:
Can write MRW:
Can write RAM:
```

---

```
root ~ # ls /dev/sr*
ls: cannot access /dev/sr*: No such file or directory
```

---

```
root ~ # wodim --devices
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

---

```
root ~ # lshw -C disk


*-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST500LT012-1DG14
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: SDM1
       serial: S3P3RLS3
       size: 465GiB (500GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=7ae6e531-9898-4c7c-8c35-41b4fdb9374a logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

---

**Expected output from above, this taken from the system, while a dvd was mounted, which is often successful, I need to know why the disks can disconnect/umount/dissapear at any time.**

```
*-disk                                                                   
       description: ATA Disk                                               
       product: ST500LT012-1DG14                                           
       vendor: Seagate                                                     
       physical id: 0.0.0                                                  
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0                                              
       logical name: /dev/sda                                              
       version: SDM1                                                       
       serial: S3P3RLS3                                                    
       size: 465GiB (500GB)                                                
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt                  
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=7ae6e531-9898-4c7c-8c35-41b4fdb9374a logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096                                   
  *-cdrom                                                                  
       description: DVD-RAM writer                                         
       product: DVD+-RW GU90N                                              
       vendor: HL-DT-ST                                                    
       physical id: 0.0.0                                                  
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0                                              
       logical name: /dev/cdrom                                            
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       logical name: /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT
       version: A100
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
          logical name: /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT
          configuration: mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted
```

---

```
root ~ # eject
eject: /dev/cdrom: not found mountpoint or device with the given name
```

---

```
root ~ # eject -t
eject: /dev/cdrom: not found mountpoint or device with the given name
```

---

```
root ~ # cat /var/log/messages | grep udisks
Sep 21 05:15:08 Hostname udisksd[3366]: Mounted /dev/sr0 at /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT on behalf of uid 1000
Sep 21 11:52:27 Hostname udisksd[3366]: Cleaning up mount point /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT (device 11:0 no longer exist)
Sep 21 21:46:56 Hostname udisksd[3366]: Mounted /dev/sr0 at /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT on behalf of uid 1000
Sep 22 00:30:06 Hostname udisksd[3366]: Cleaning up mount point /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT (device 11:0 no longer exist)
```

*Behaviour of the dvd drive, disk's and dvd's are mounted in* `/run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT` *and work, but then they can disconnect at any time, and when they disconnect, they don't show up anywhere in the system, and I am unable to eject the disk.*

When I close the lid, the laptop is set to "sleep", I did this 4 hours ago, and when I revoke it one hour ago the dvd in the drive got mounted in `/run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT`.
This is how it is now:

```
root ~ # df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-3                         89G   63G   21G  76% /
devtmpfs                         5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            5.9G   80K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.9G  968K  5.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            5.9G   20K  5.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-home  360G  222G  134G  63% /home
/dev/sda2                        477M  131M  317M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                        200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sr0                         6.7G  6.7G     0 100% /run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT
```

---

Here is the output of the cd-drive command: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vhttHGJX)

Here is the output of the cd-info command: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bPG2yp0L)

Comment: if the CD is not identified by `k3b` there is a chance `k3b` does not run with enough access rights. Initially, you should try to run `k3b` as root and verify if the CD is identified properly.

Comment: Looks like everything you're doing is correct to diagnose the problem. From my understand its a bad cd driver, bad hardware. When you mentioned "It kicked in last time without me doing anything" then it worked last time but now its a hardware issue. Either it mounts the drive, but if it worked once and it doesn't mount again, it all concludes to hardware failure in my opinion.

Comment: Try my tips in this U&L Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110993/getting-capabilities-of-my-cd-dvd-drive-when-wodim-devices-doesnt-work. `wodim` can be a pain. Also are you running GNOME? Does Nautilus not show the DVD drive when you insert DVD's into the drive?

Comment: @slm I'm running KDE, two day's ago I inserted a dvd movie, it showed up in Dolphin and if I "df -h" it was mounted on /var/run/media/username/MOUNTPOINT, but it's been sitting in the drive since and most of that time it isn't found anywhere and is not mounted, also I can't get it out of the drive. Think if I reboot it gets detected.I have never had problem getting the disk out more than few hours.

Comment: Does the `eject` or `eject -t` commands not work?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your query, execute the following commands and verify the output for errors:

```
$ lsblk
$ lspci
$ dmesg | egrep -i --color 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer'
$ cdrecord -prcap dev=/dev/cdrom
$ ls -l /dev/sr0
$ x-cd-roas
```

Generally, the reported issue might be due to the following reasons,

- CD drive does not connected properly;
- Maybe the drivers need to be updated;
- Maybe the port you are connecting it to is damaged.

So, first off, check that the connection port is working well, also check whether the CD drive is getting power or not.

Also Update the CD drivers.

If issue still persists there is an problem in CD drive.

Comment: Is the last command the same as this:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-CD-Roast ?

Comment: It's a laptop I'm not connecting it to any ports. I already have the output from the dmesg command in my question. I'm not trying to write a cd as such, I'm trying to figure out why my cd's and dvd's sometimes don't mount, and sometimes mount but can disconnect at any time. I already have the ls command in my output.

Comment: CD Drivers for linux?  More likely, I'd say, that your hardware is flakey or your connections are flakey.  The 3 things I'd say to consider are: 1) optical drive doesn't have a secure connection ( usually they're removable ) and when jostled, randomly disconnects /reconnects ; 2) optical drive is broken inside, either flakey connection somewhere internally or bad firmware or etc; 3) power supply problems.  I doubt it has anything to do with drivers or software.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an entry corresponding to your cd/dvd device in your fstab, 
try to comment it and reboot. Perhaps there is some interferences between automount and fstab options.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this.

```
eject /dev/sr0
```

because it will work when

```
eject -r
```

won't work. If you are having issues, then make sure that you are using super user privileges in case the issue is permissions.

Comment: `eject /dev/sr0` isn't going to work if `/dev/sr0` doesn't exist, and the question says `ls /dev/sr*` reports `ls: cannot access /dev/sr*: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

**I've been through this a few times. I have series of questions and suggestions for you.**

- what is the version of fedora?
- does your laptop cd-rom slide out?
- does it blink when you boot to pc?
- have you updated the hardware with yum?

  *Try inserting a cd with data and see if it pops up.*

  *If your cd is properly initialized it should pop up.*

Comment: I don't have that laptop anymore but the question still shows some good info on the subject, thanks for your answer!