# determining dvd drive capability

Tags: linux, dvd

Aside from checking the manual for a particular DVD drive, is there any way to determine if a DVD drive supports DVD +R/-R (DL) for both reading and writing?

In Windows, Nero InfoTool is a convenient way to determine the capabilities of a drive. Is there an equivalent tool (or method) for linux?

Comment: see also the answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110993)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
less /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info
```

to display the functionality of the DVD drive.  `0` means an option is not enabled and a `1` signifies an option that is available.

If you have `libcdio` installed you can use the `cd-drive` command for more detailed drive information.

`K3b` is a graphical tool you can use that is similar to `Nero`.

Navigate to:
Settings ==> Configure K3b ==> Devices

This should display the `DVD+R` status.

Comment: As for /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info I see options for "Can read DVD" and "Can write DVD-R" but I don't see any option listed for +R and nothing about dual layer.

As for cd-drive command, I see "DVD+R Feature" listed under Core Feature and "DVD+R - DVD Recordable" and "DVD+R Double Layer - DVD Recordable Double Layer - on" under Profile List Feature. 

Under Reading... only "Can read DVD-ROM" and under Writing... "Can write DVD-R" = Yes, but no specific mention of "Can write DVD+R". Can write DVD-RW and DVD+RW are both No.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [cd-drive](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cd-drive) which is included in `Fedora` for example in `libcdio` package. When you run command:

```
cd-drive
```

a possible output could be:

> Profile List Feature
>          DVD+R Double Layer - DVD Recordable Double Layer
>           DVD+R - DVD Recordable
>           DVD+RW - DVD Rewritable
>           DVD-R - Double-Layer Sequential Recording
>           Re-recordable DVD using Sequential Recording
>           Re-recordable DVD using Restricted Overwrite
>           Re-writable DVD
>           Re-recordable DVD using Sequential recording
>           Read only DVD
>           CD-RW Re-writable Compact Disc capable
>           Write once Compact Disc capable
>           Read only Compact Disc capable
>           ...